# NSIS installer not working with InTune

Tags: windows, nsis, intune

So, I've reviewed as much documentation as I can about InTune and NSIS and I can't seem to figure this out.

I have an NSIS silent installer that (when executed locally, even as system via psexec) runs without any issue at all but seems to do nothing when deployed with software deployment with InTune.   The installer calls a batch file that runs a vbscript to enumerate all the users on a system then changes all their passwords:  See below for source on all of the abovementioned.

**NSIS Installer**

```
Name "Silent"
OutFile "silent.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel admin

Function .onInit
SetSilent silent
FunctionEnd

Section ""
    File FindUsers.vbs
        File un.bat
    Exec un.bat
SectionEnd
```

**VBS Script**

```
Set exclude = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
exclude.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
exclude.Add "HomeGroupUser$", True
exclude.Add "Guest", True

Set accounts = GetObject("WinNT://.")
accounts.Filter = Array("user")
For Each user In accounts
  If Not exclude.Exists(user.Name) Then WScript.Echo user.Name
Next
```

And lastly the batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set newpw=Test
for /f "delims=" %%u in ('cscript //NoLogo FindUsers.vbs') do (
  echo "net user "%%u" "%newpw%""
  net user "%%u" "%newpw%"
)
```

Why wouldn't this run properly when deployed with intune but would run properly when executed as a user or as system?

Answer (score 1):

should be [ExecShell](https://github.com/NSIS-Handbook/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/ExecShell.md)

```
ExecShell open un.bat
```

Comment: Man, if you're right I'm going to hug you.   I'll try to do a deploy now.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to have worked either.

Answer (score 1):

you might have to specify an output directory as well, see [SetOutPath](https://github.com/NSIS-Handbook/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/SetOutPath.md)

```
SetOutPath $TEMP
File "un.bat" # will be extracted to $TEMP
ExecShell open "$TEMP\un.bat"
```